# How to completly remove packages installed by cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to learn cabal, and have tested several my own little projects, now I want to clean them up.

Basically, if I am working without a `sandbox`, my workflow is:

1. run `cabal init`
2. edit `src/Mylib.hs`, and then edit `mylibname.cabal` file
3. run `cabal build`
4. run `cabal repl` and test my code
5. run `cabal install`

Now, I see my own project:

1. installed into `~/.cabal/lib/x86-64-linux-ghc-7.10.1`
2. registered in `~/.ghc/package.conf.d`

I can write `import Mylib` in my other haskell source code, so I think the package is successfully installed.

Then I want to uninstall the package, as the package itself is just meaningless experiment code.

I read [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install) article, who says that:

> There is no "cabal uninstall" command. You can only unregister
>   packages with ghc-pkg:
>
> ```
>  ghc-pkg unregister
> ```

so I run

```
ghc-pkg unregister mylibname
```

Now, it seems that the package is unregistered in `~/ghc/package.conf.d`, however, there is still a compiled library in  `~/.cabal/lib/x86-64-linux-ghc-7.10.1`.

So, how could I completly remove my project, could I just `rm -rf` the library in `~/.cabal`?

Answer (score 8):

You can delete the files yourself from the packages directory. However, the reason no command to do so is provided is there's in general no guarantee something may not have linked against them elsewhere, and so such deletions may cause breakages. That said, there's also a tool that goes and does the deletion for you if you *really* want it.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-uninstall

And there's a tool with a bit more functionality that also lets you figure out what packages have no reverse deps, so at least no other *packages* break:

https://github.com/iquiw/cabal-delete

Comment: What a lazy implementation of a package manager. And that's lazy in a really bad sense. I know a lot of people who simply quit Haskell because the package management is so difficult to deal with. We need to abstract away these issues.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro - Probably why many people use Stack now, but I personally prefer Cabal when it doesn't bite me in the backside...

Comment: _in general no guarantee something may not have linked against them elsewhere_ isn't this, more in general, true for any software? Any software has dependencies on other software, and if we remove the latter we break the former. A package manager should keep track, I think, of these dependency relations, so it could tell the user "oh, no, if you remove this you break that".

Comment: Except these are packages that _users can link against independently of the package manager_.