# remove downloads from cabal installation

Tags: cabal, idris, cabal-install

I wanted to install Idris, so I first installed Haskell and then wrote cabal update and cabal install idris in the terminal. However, after downloading and installing lots of components, the installation finally failed on some packages. I then did the installation via the Windows-.exe from idris-lang.org and now it runs fine, but I want to remove what was downloaded and installed before with the cabal command. Any idea how to do that? Is there such a command like "cabal deinstall idris" or something? Or would it affect the other installation too?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332033/how-to-completly-remove-packages-installed-by-cabal

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shersh, but I don't understand the thread. I really don't know anything about cabal or Haskell or ghc, I just installed Haskell yesterday and then did the cabal install idris command. 
So maybe you could tell me, where the things that are downloaded and installed because of that command are saved? Are they all in the cabal and the ghc folder I found under C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming or also somewhere else? And would it destroy the Idris installation I did via the installation.exe from the homepage afterwards if I deleted the cabal-things?

Comment: If I did a system recovery with a date before the download and installation of Haskell and before I wrote the cabal install idris - command, would it delete all files that cabal created?

Comment: `cabal` stores all downloaded data in some folder. On `Ubuntu` it's `~/.cabal`. According to internet, on windows this folder is `C:\username\AppData\Roaming\cabal` or just what you said. `cabal` doesn't install thing's in several places hopefully. So deleting that folder you found is okay and will clean up everything that was installed. `idris` is just an executable that put into that folder.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Shersh, that's exactly what I wanted to know. 1) So did I understand it correctly, that everything that was downloaded and installed following the cabal install idris - command is placed in the folder "cabal" which includes the folders "doc", "logs", "packages", "x86_64-windows-ghc-8.0.2" and two files named "config" and "world"?

2) I can delete the whole cabal-folder manually and don't have to put a special command in the Haskell-shell?

3) If I delete the folder it doesn't have any influence on my (with the .exe-installation) correctly installed idris?

Comment: 4) There's also a folder "ghc" in the Roaming-path which was created just before the creation of the "cabal"-folder. - So can I delete that one, too or was it created along with the Haskell-installation and not with the cabal install idris - command?

Comment: Yes, `ghc` folder contains compiler for Haskell programming language. `cabal` is written in Haskell, Idris is written in Haskell as well so `ghc` is needed to build stuff. But once you got Idris installed you don't need `ghc`. Though, as you already noticed, that `idris` executable is in `cabal` folder, removing this folder w/o copying `idris` somewhere else will also remove that executable.

Comment: Okay, so if I delete the ghc folder now and need it any time in the future, it will be created again? Or do I have to install Haskell another time then? 
I don't see anything called "idris" in the cabal folder. What is an executable and how do I find it? 

The .exe installation created a folder called "idris" containing the folders "doc", "libs", "mingw", "idris.exe", "idris-codegen-c.exe", "idris-codegen-javascript.exe" and "idris-codegen-node.exe" in a path far away from the cabal-folder. So does this folder contain the needed executable, too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completly remove packages installed by cabal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332033/how-to-completly-remove-packages-installed-by-cabal)