# Cabal installed packages cache cleanup issue

Tags: haskell, cabal

If I give following command:

```
cabal install <pkgname>
```

the package and its dependencies will be downloaded and installed.

Do these packages remain in some place like cache and take up space? If so, how can these be deleted to increase space?

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly the source code is stored in `~/.cabal/packages/`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332033/how-to-completly-remove-packages-installed-by-cabal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The tarballs are downloaded to the `~/.cabal/packages` directory, and can be deleted from there. The packages are installed to the `~./cabal/store` directory (with v2-install) and elsewhere in `~/.cabal` for v1-install. But you shouldn't delete either incrementally, as you'll almost certainly break dependencies.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for a built+cached package and couldn't find it because the package name was mangled from `configuration-tools` to `cnfgrtn-tls-0.6.1-115f3969`.